# Oracle create table using with clause

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

Can I create a table from a query formed using `with` clause?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Sure:

```
CREATE TABLE t
AS 
WITH some_data AS ( 
   SELECT 1 as some_value 
   FROM dual

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT 2 
   FROM dual
) 
SELECT * 
FROM some_data
```

Comment: What about with multiple defined tables? I.e. if you have "WITH x as (...), y as (...)"?

Comment: Does not work in oracle 12c. Oracle says 'ora-32034: unsupported use of with clause'. Everything after `create table t as` should be placed inside `select * from (...here...)`. Just like in @saleh helou's answer.

Comment: @Poolka: [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=26afd3073169c324db14ac586cfb957c) even on Oracle 11

Comment: @Poolka I first had the same error, until I realized that the WITH and SELECT within the CREATE statement can apparently not be within parentheses: instead of `CREATE TABLE t AS ( WITH some_data AS (...) SELECT * FROM some_data )`, it should be `CREATE TABLE t AS WITH some_date AS (...) SELECT * FROM some_data`.

Comment: @SanderVandenHautte Thank you for the comment. Now i get it. It's so non-intuitive. I used to add outer select query `create as (select * from ( with as ... ))` to make it work. Like in the other answer here. Never thought that parentheses must or must not be used around statements.

Answer (score 3):

The CREATE TABLE table_name AS statement creates a table based on a select statement. The solution for a with clause will be :

```
CREATE TABLE t
AS 
SELECT * FROM (
WITH some_data AS ( 
   SELECT 1 as some_value 
   FROM dual

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT 2 
   FROM dual
) 
);
```

Comment: Thats a nearly exact copy of the former answer.... any reason for that?

Comment: made sense to me more than the first answer... although it's practically the same. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For multiple CTE (common table expressions; i.e. multiple `WITH` clause), I found the same syntax worked. i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE schema.table_name as 
WITH table1 as (SELECT 1),
table2 as (SELECT 2)

select * from table2
```

will create the `table_name` in the `schema` from the `select` statement