# Creating a table in Oracle using a query that contains a WITH clause within it

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table, with-clause

I am basically trying to run a create table statement using a query that has a with clause within it, but I am getting an error. Is there a different way to run this? The query statement is something like this:

CREATE TABLE DATA_TABLE AS
(
  WITH X AS
  (.....)

SELECT * FROM X
)

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: In the example you've given, using a 'WITH()' cluase is a complete waste of time. Maybe if you showed the actual code we could have a guess at what you aretrying to acheive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429679) what you want.

```
CREATE TABLE t
AS 
WITH some_data AS ( 
   SELECT 1 as some_value 
   FROM dual

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT 2 
   FROM dual
) 
SELECT * 
FROM some_data
```